# Returning a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, twitter

I am messing around with Python 3 and searching Twitter. I have everything working on my side in terms of Twitter keys and oauth tokens. The code below will return the text for the most re-tweeted messages as a list (sometimes with duplicates, unfortunately). I know most everything in Twitter is in dictionaries. My question is this: how would I get my function to return as a list of dictionaries?

```
def mostRetweetedByUser(user_name):
    tweet_list = []
    search = twitter_api.search.tweets(q=user_name, count = 200)
    tweets = search['statuses']
    most_tweets = search['statuses'][0]['retweet_count']
    for i in range(len(search['statuses'])):
        if search['statuses'][i]['retweet_count'] > most_tweets:
            tweet_list.append(search['statuses'][i]['text'])
    return tweet_list
```

Comment: If you want dictionaries, why do you explicitly `.append` only the text to your output list?

Comment: Please show sample input and output, as suggested in the posting guideline [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.

Comment: Sorry about that. I get the tweets back like this:["RT @KatreaseS_freep: Very sad news. Who didn't grow up on their music? https://t.co/Oy4QOsfgwE"]

Comment: I guess I was just expecting the tweets to be in dictionary form, or at least I was looking to get just the tweet text in dictionary form. Maybe I'm just in over my head.

Answer (score 1):

You are explicitly appending **only the text** to the output list with `tweet_list.append(search['statuses'][i]['text'])`. Replacing that line with `tweet_list.append(search['statuses'][i])` would give you the full dictionary in your output.